# Sort dictionary on key only in debugger in VisualStudio

Tags: c#, dictionary, debugging

I use a object based on Dictionary in my application.
When debugging (and only when i inspect the Dictionary) i would like to wiew the content of the dictionary but sorted on key.

I know that i could use SortedDictionary instead of Dictionary but the performance is poor compare to Dictionary and i don't want to affect performance.

I don't want to have a "#if debug" condition either.

Is it possible ?

Comment: You could write a custom visualizer for that case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-visualizers-of-data?view=vs-2019

Comment: I could do that but it will take time. With a method returning the SortedDictionary i can do this quicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a [DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggertypeproxyattribute?view=netframework-4.8) on your class that is used when/if you debug. This proxy has to sort the data for you.

Article: [Enhancing Debugging with the Debugger Display Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/enhancing-debugging-with-the-debugger-display-attributes)

Example using a (senseless) child of a `Dictionary<string,int>`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

internal class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Derives from a Dictionary that is not sorted
    /// </summary>
    [DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(DictDebugView))]
    public class MyDictionary : Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Prepares unsorted dummy data
        /// </summary>
        public void PopulateDemoData()
        {
            foreach (char t in "GERZWIQSFHIWE")
               this[new string(t, t / 10)] = t;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Is used as proxy for display
        /// </summary>
        internal class DictDebugView
        {
            private readonly SortedDictionary<string, int> sorted;
            public DictDebugView(Dictionary<string, int> data)
                => sorted = new SortedDictionary<string, int>(data);

            /// <summary>
            /// Create the displayed KeyValuePairs
            /// </summary>
            [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Collapsed)]
            public IList<KeyValuePair<string,int>> Keys
            {
                get => sorted.Select(kvp => kvp).ToList();
            }
        }
    } 

    public static MyDictionary MyProp { get; } = new MyDictionary();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var md = new MyDictionary();
        md.PopulateDemoData();

        var k = new Dictionary<string,int>(md); 

        Console.ReadLine();
    } 
}
```

If you place a breakpoint and debug you get a sorted output for your class with internal DebuggerTypeProxy:

[image: Using the DebuggerTypeProxy]

and unsorted output for the "normal" dictionary that does not use any proxy to display its data:

[image: as plain dict]

Comment: And in Raw View there is the original one

Answer (score 1):

Using this in watch :

```
new SortedDictionary<string,object>(dictionary)
```

or a method Debug with that return the sortedDictionary

Answer (score -1):

Try to put following line of code into watch during debugging you will find desire result.

```
l_oDictionary.OrderBy(key => key.Key);
```

Comment: It is not a IEnumerable, so LINQ is not available